# Concurrency and Replicated Requests, what is time.After() for?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm reading concurrency in Go and getting very close to the end! Overall it's been a great read. In one of the examples, the author is describing how to simulate request replication. The code example is this:

```
func main() {
    doWork := func(
        done <-chan interface{},
        id int,
        wg *sync.WaitGroup,
        result chan<- int,
    ) {
        started := time.Now()
        defer wg.Done()

        // Simulate random load
        simulatedLoadTime := time.Duration(1*rand.Intn(5)) * time.Second

        /** use two separate select blocks because we want to send/receive two different values, the time.After (receive) and the id (send).
        / if they were in the same select block, then we could only use one value at a time, the other will get lost. */
        select {
        // do not want to return on <-done because we still want to log the time it took
        case <-done:
        case <-time.After(simulatedLoadTime):
        }

        select {
        case <-done:
        case result <- id:
        }

        took := time.Since(started)
        // Display how long handlers would have taken
        if took < simulatedLoadTime {
            took = simulatedLoadTime
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v took %v\n", id, took)
    }

    done := make(chan interface{})
    result := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go doWork(done, i, &wg, result)
    }

    firstReturned := <-result
    close(done)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Received an answer from #%v\n", firstReturned)
}
```

The one line I don't understand is `case <-time.After(simulatedLoadTime)`. Why is this here? When are we ever making use of the value being returned from that channel. How is that channel even being communicated outside of the select block? For whatever reason, that line seems to be pretty integral in synchronizing the timing of results, because if I were to replace it with a `default:` the results are out of sync.

Comment: *"When are we ever making use of the value being returned from that channel."* Never, what is made use of is the receive operation rather than the value being received. *"How is that channel even being communicated outside of the select block?"* The channel is not communicated. The message-receive however causes the `select` to stop blocking. The `select` blocks until either `done` receives a message or `time.After(simulatedLoadTime)` receives a message. If you add `default`, then `select` won't block at all.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements *"2. If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a **`default` case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed**."*

Comment: @mkopriva that's awesome, thanks for clarifying! I took a look at https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations.  Does that mean `time.After` is effectively irrelevant to the process? What's the point of having two separate select blocks if we never use the value? The 2nd select block seems to make sense as the sole block since it also handles `<-done`

Comment: If `<-done` is taking too long to finish its job, `time.After` can be used as the alternative path. For example a "limit" of how long should a `select` wait for the other `cases`. *(I don't know how exactly it is used in the question's code or the link in the comment as I've only scanned the code and do not understand its purpose)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered-by-comment (see [mkopriva's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446569/concurrency-and-replicated-requests-what-is-time-after-for#comment115706608_65446569)) but let me provide an "answer-ified" version.

First, a small aside:

> ```
> done := make(chan interface{})
> ```

I usually see `make(chan struct{})` here.  Since there's never any actual value sent, the type of the channel doesn't matter much, but sending an empty `struct` value takes no space at all, while sending an empty `interface{}` takes space.<sup>1</sup>

Now, what we're going to do here, in a closure,<sup>2</sup> is:

- wait (or at least pretend to wait) for some server to answer;
- if a timeout occurs, stop waiting for the server; and
- deliver our ID to a result channel

**or** if the `done` channel is closed (indicating that someone else beat us to doing everything), not bother with any of the above.

As a complication, we're also going to log how long we waited, even if we did not get an answer.

The main goroutine:

- creates the `done` channel, whose only purpose is to be `close`d so that receives from it immediately return their lack-of-a-value zero-value at EOF;
- spins off some number (10, to be specific) of these worker goroutines;
- waits for the first one to deliver a result (possibly a lack-of-result due to timeout, result)
- closes the `done` channel to make the remaining workers terminate; and
- prints the final result.

The thing we're interested in is why the closure's code is written with the code fragment:

```golang
    select {
    case <-done:
    case <-time.After(simulatedLoadTime):
    }
```

in it.

The trick here is that `select` evaluates *all its alternatives up front*.  So it evaluates the `done` channel, but also calls `time.After()`, before beginning the selection process.  The `select` then waits for *whichever one has a value or is at end-of-channel and therefore has EOF*, whichever occurs first.

If *no* goroutine has sent a result back to the main goroutine yet, the `done` channel will not be closed.  *All* goroutines will, at this point, block on the `done` channel.  But all goroutines will also have called `time.After`.

The `time.After` code kicks off a goroutine that, after some amount of time, will send the current time on a channel.  It then returns that channel.  Hence at least *one* of those two `<-` operations will complete: either the `done` channel will be, or get, closed, and we'll get a zero value on it due to the EOF, or the channel returned by `time.After` will have a time sent to it, and we'll receive that value.  No matter which value we actually get, we drop the value on the floor, but the fact that one of the two `<-` operators *will* unblock eventually, guarantees that this goroutine will eventually be able to proceed.

The event that occurs *first* will be the closing of the `done` channel, or the receiving of the time.  We don't know which one this is because we don't know how long it will take for the `done` channel to get closed, but the *upper bound* on the time is however long the duration was that we passed to `time.After`.  That is, either the `done` happens (eventually), or, after the time we chose, the `time.After` part happens.  One of them definitely happens.

Now, if we didn't care about *logging the time we took*, we could write this as:

```
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case <-time.After(simulatedLoadTime):
        // everything else happens here
    }
```

But note the comment in the original code:

> ```
> // do not want to return on <-done because we still want to log ...
> ```

So that explains the lack of a `return`.

Having timed out, we must now *try* to send our ID to the main goroutine.  However, we might not be able to do that: some other worker goroutine might beat us to that send, and the main goroutine only reads one value from the channel.  To make sure we don't get stuck here, we have another `select`.  We'll *try* to send our ID, but stop if the `done` channel either is now, or gets, closed.  Then we'll log and return.

---

<sup>1</sup>I keep thinking Go should have a predeclared empty struct type just as a convenience and style thing.  We'd use this here for our `done` channel.  We'd use this for maps that exist solely to act as sets too, except that they would also have a predeclared convenience-and-style-only type.  But that's another matter entirely.

<sup>2</sup>There's no particularly good reason to use a closure here.  An un-exported plain function would work just as well.  Given that we *are* using a closure, we could capture the `done` channel, the `wg *WaitGroup` value, and the `result` channel instead of taking them as arguments.  It's not clear to me why the author chose to write it as a closure-that-could-be-a-function, then not bother with any of the nice things a closure gets us.

Comment: Bless you and @mkopriva